# Orbit Slider with Wordpress - Add background-color fadein/out per slide

Tags: jquery, wordpress, background-color, fading, orbit

I have been searching forums and google for 3 hours... no luck.

I am using the Orbit Slider Wordpress plug-in, all works fine, however.

I would like to add in a function to the jQuery file that changes the background-color of a custom div I added, with ID `slide-bgcolor-change`. "If there is a better easier way... I'm all ears"

Here is an example of what I want my div id `slide-bgcolor-change` to do via js or query:

Slide 1 has background-color of black in div id `slide-bgcolor-change`
as Slide 1 and background-color of black fades out

Slide 2 fades in with background-color of blue

... and so on, up to 5 slides

I have not done any customization yet to the original files. To view the files I am working with go [here](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-orbit-slider/).

Please Help.